# maplibre-gl-leaflet treating drag as click

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, maplibre-gl

I have a vector tile set that I need to display as part of an existing Leaflet based application, and so I am using maplibre-gl-leaflet to render the vector data. I also need to attach a handler that can access the properties of an individual feature when it is clicked on. I couldn't figure out how to do that at the Leaflet level, but by adding the handler to the actual Maplibre map, it works great.

```
var glLayer = L.maplibreGL({
            pane: 'overlayPane', // needed because the vector basemap layer hides it otherwise
            interactive: true,

}).addTo(map);
const gl = glLayer.getMaplibreMap();
// add vector source and layer here
    gl.on('click','points', function (e) {
        debugger
    });
```

The problem is that if you drag the map and the spot that you drag on is where one of the vector features are, after drag end, treats that as a click and calls my handler. I want it to not do that and just let the drag event be handled as a drag event.

I can't reproduce this issue in a vanilla MapLibre map. Is there a way to fix it with maplibre-gl-leaflet?

Live example at the codepen https://codepen.io/dandormont-the-decoder/full/abRyMPm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to catch `mousedown` event, save mouse position and then on `click` event compare mouse position with saved mouse position. If position is the same that means it was actual `click` event, not end of mouse drag.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var downPos;
gl.on('mousedown','points', function (e) {
  downPos = e.point;
});
gl.on('click','points', function (e) {
  if ((parseInt(e.point.x) == parseInt(downPos.x)) && (parseInt(e.point.y) == parseInt(downPos.y))) {
   console.log('click');
  }
});
```